# SWRL tab is not working in Protege-5.0.0-beta-23.

Tags: protege, swrl

I am using Protege 5.0 beta version. This version supports SWRL but whenever I click on its tab, I only get a blank screen.

Here is a snapshot

[Protege 5.0 SWRL tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mv9F.png)

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you get any error in the console?

Comment: No, I am not getting any errors. I am new to Protege. I created an ontology and I am trying to write some SWRL rules but the tab isn't showing anything, just a blank screen

Comment: There is a .jre file of swrl in the plugin which came with the package when i downloaded it. 
Secondly, I have seen plenty of tutorials suggesting that in 5.0 version, the swrl api needs to be installed (something with maven). The tutorials show linux commands but I am working on windows. 

The sqwrl tab also shows only a blank screen.

Comment: Can you open a command prompt in the protégé folder and run the run.bat file from there? This will allow you to see any startup errors.

Comment: Problem solved. I had jdk 7 installed on my system. I think the plugin was designed for jdk 8. So I installed jdk 8, updated the system, changed the environmental variable, restarted it and BAM it started working.

Answer (score 0):

By downloading Protege-5.0.0-RC1 and installing Swrl tab plugins it works.